Why is my vi.spyOn on a mocked function not recording calls in Vitest?
I'm testing a function called compareExcelFiles in Vitest, and I'm trying to spy on the readFile function it calls internally. Despite setting up the spy with vi.spyOn, the calls to readFile aren't being recorded during the test. Instead, the spy shows zero calls, even though the function executes successfully.
Expected behavior: The spy on readFile should record two calls with specific arguments.
Actual behavior: readFileSpy shows zero calls in the test output, even though the compareExcelFiles function logs the correct data, indicating that readFile did execute.
Here's my code:
compareExcelFiles implementation:
export const compareExcelFiles = async (userFile: File, templateFile: File):        Promise<boolean | null> => {
  try {
    const [templateData, userData] = await Promise.all([
      readFile(templateFile, true),
      readFile(userFile, true)
    ]);

    // Verificar que la primera fila de cada hoja en el mismo índice sea igual
    for (let i = 0; i < templateData.length - 1; i++) {
      const templateRow = templateData[i];
      const userRow = userData[i];

      if (!userData[i]) {
        console.log("Número de hojas no coincide.");
        return null;
      }

      if (JSON.stringify(templateRow) !== JSON.stringify(userRow)) {
        console.log(`La primera fila de la hoja en el índice ${i} no coincide.`);
        return null;
      }
    }

    console.log("Los archivos tienen el mismo número de hojas y primeras filas     idénticas en los mismos índices.");
    return true;

  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error leyendo archivos:', error);
    return null;
  }
};`

Test Code
`import { describe, it, expect, vi, afterEach, beforeEach } from 'vitest';
import { compareExcelFiles, readFile } from '@/components/excel-reader';
import * as ExcelReader from '@/components/excel-reader';

describe('compareExcelFiles', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    vi.clearAllMocks();
    vi.resetAllMocks();
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    vi.clearAllMocks(); 
    vi.resetAllMocks();  // Clears all mocks and restores original implementations
  });

  it('should return true when userFile matches the first row of each sheet in     templateFile', async () => {
    // Spy directly on readFile function in the imported ExcelReader
    const readFileSpy = vi.spyOn(ExcelReader, 'readFile')
      .mockResolvedValueOnce([
        ['Header1', 'Header2'],  // Template file's sheets
        ['Header3', 'Header4'],
        ['Header5', 'Header6'],
      ])
      .mockResolvedValueOnce([
        ['Header1', 'Header2'],  // User file's sheets
        ['Header3', 'Header4'],
      ]);

    console.log("Before compareExcelFiles call");

    const result = await compareExcelFiles(new File([], 'user.xlsx'), new File([],    'template.xlsx'));
    console.log("Registered calls on readFileSpy:", readFileSpy.mock.calls);

    expect(readFileSpy).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(1, expect.any(File), true);
    expect(readFileSpy).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(2, expect.any(File), true);
    expect(readFileSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
    expect(result).toBe(true);

    readFileSpy.mockRestore();
  });
});`

What I've Tried:
Verified the module import paths and that compareExcelFiles references readFile from the correct module.
Used console.log inside compareExcelFiles to confirm that readFile executes and returns the expected data.
Tried vi.clearAllMocks() and vi.resetAllMocks() in beforeEach and afterEach to ensure a clean state.
Checked readFileSpy.mock.calls, which always returns an empty array.
My Question:
Why isn’t the readFileSpy recording calls, even though readFile executes within compareExcelFiles? Is there something I'm missing with vi.spyOn in Vitest that might cause this behavior?
